# Embed asciidoc in Azure DevOps wiki

Tags: azure, azure-devops, asciidoc, azure-devops-wiki

Does anyone have a solution how to embed asciidoc/generated HTML into the Azure DevOps Wiki?

As a first way just for watch (integrate HTML from asciidoc in the wiki for other users).
I also have problems to access a committed html file to the wiki by a link from a markdown wiki page.

(Second: integration with possibility to edit adoc source by users)

Comment: As phrased the question is difficult to understand. Presumably you wish to render HTML in an Azure DevOps Wiki page. Azure DevOps Wiki supports HTML in its page content. I don't recommend it but you could paste HTML right into the page. The Wiki should render the HTML. Alternatively, if you wish to put the generated HTML files directly into the Wiki, you could clone its underlying repository (the Wiki's that is) and then name your HTML file(s) with a .md extension. Once checked-in, committed, and pushed (to master/origin) they should be visible directly in your Wiki. Either should work.

Comment: Please upvote [DevCommunity - Add Preview for AsciiDoc (.adoc) files in addition to Markdown](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/add-preview-for-asciidoc-adoc-files-in-addition-to/365715) to have MS prioritize this feature.

Answer (score 3):

> how to embed asciidoc/generated HTML into the Azure DevOps Wiki?

As of this time, however, using asciidoc in Azure DevOps wiki is not supported. You can suggest a feature in [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21). The Microsoft's Product team will carefully consider your suggestions based on the votes.

> I also have problems to access a committed html file to the wiki by a link from a markdown wiki page.

In wiki, all pages exist in the form of a markdown. That is, if you create a new page called `a.html`, but you actually create a new file called `a.html.md`.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone have a solution how to embed asciidoc/generated HTML into the Azure DevOps Wiki?

There is an Under Review user voice about this on our main forum for product suggestions:

[Azure DevOps wiki editor - support for HTML & rich text](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/542414/azure-devops-wiki-editor-support-for-html-rich-tex.html)

currently, HTML tag support in wiki pages, we could link the html file to the wiki by a link like you said in the first way:

```
<p>
 
 [A markdown link](https://microsoft.com) 
</p>
```

If you have problems to access the link, please share the error log you met when you access the link. And please check your premission by Wiki security:

[image]

You could also open the link in the browser directly to check if you can access the link.